# Trying to download Blob via PHP / MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, download, blob

This is one I just can't figure out: I have successfully built an upload feature on a web page to upload files to a MySQL Database. When I go on the server and open them via phpMyAdmin, they all look fine... txt, jpg, pdf, etc.

Yet, after putting together THIS thing (below) to download it, I get a strange problem: All of the text documents (and all other types of files, after I change the extension to 'txt') contain HTML code of the page itself, followed by the original content!

Also, different browsers display differently after the POST. When trying to download a txt file, IE will show the correct data in the ECHO on the page itself (no downloading) with an error message just before it:

> Warning: Header may not contain more than a single header, new line detected. in C:\wamp\www\ace\dmain.php on line 82.
>
> Line 82 is 'header("Content-length...'

Neither Firefox nor Chrome show anything. They just allow me to download it.

Here's the code:

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST['downloadid'])) {
    $fileid = $_POST['downloadid'];
    try {
      $sql = "SELECT * FROM `datastore` WHERE `id` = '".$fileid."'";
        $results = $pdo->query($sql);echo $sql;
        while ($row = $results->fetch()) {
            $filename = $row['filename'];
            $mimetype = $row['mimetype'];
            $filedata = $row['filedata'];
            header("Content-length: strlen($filedata)");
            header("Content-type: $mimetype");
            header("Content-disposition: download; filename=$filename"); //disposition of download forces a download
            echo $filedata; 
            // die();
        } //of While
    } //try
    catch (PDOException $e) {
        $error = '<br>Database ERROR fetching requested file.';
        echo $error;
        die();    
    } //catch
} //isset
?>
```

Comment: Yikes. You're using PDO and _still_ not binding parameters and you're making yourself vulnerable to SQL injection. **Please** (for your own good) look into `bindValue` and `prepare` on PDO. You're also `echo`ing the SQL before you change headers. This will cause the headers to not be sent unless output buffering is enabled.

Comment: Yeah... I'm a bad boy. This is really for internal use only for a small set of employees, but I get the point. Will rewrite that.

Comment: Even for internal use it's important. Not much to stop an employee on the way out from causing some damage when they leave if this is how the code is written! I'm just trying to help you out. But you know better than me in your internal organization.

Comment: When it's just output, should I still bind parameters and use prepare?

Comment: Yes, you should _always_ escape. Believe me, you'll be doing a favor to yourself and your company if, when you ask, "should I escape X?" you always just answer YES.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This:

```
header("Content-length: strlen($filedata)");
```

Is not going to produce what you expect. If you look at the headers in wireshark, or another method to view the request you will see that it does not contain an integer.

Use this instead:

```
header("Content-length: ".strlen($filedata));
```

Comment: Thanks for that one! I don't get the IE message anymore, but all files still have the HTML code appended to the beginning. Gak.

Comment: Your code is currently echoing the SQL statement, do you have any other output before you echo the file data?

Comment: I removed the echo $sql after I posted this. No luck. There is other output before the <?PHP tag.

Comment: Nope. Just starts out with my header file, and contiguously goes through to the end of the page. All of the page HTML is included in the file. I've read that spaces and output before can do things to disrupt this. Should I call a separate, isolated PHP page via the form?

Comment: I think you do need to isolate this. You need to make sure its called in a context where no other html is generated.

Comment: Thanks. Just did that, and it's fixed. I don't really get it. All other code seemed fine. Just a quirk with header?

Answer (score 0):

After agonizing over fixing it in-place (that is, on the same page with the rest of the html and code), I decided to move it to a dedicated PHP page. After that, it worked fine.

Thanks for the comments!

Answer (score -1):

[here is good example and complete source](http://smartcoderszone.com/2010/09/upload-files-in-blob-type-using-mysql-and-php/)

Comment: I think this is either outdated or spam.